# "explain this" vs "explain about this"

Tags: prepositions

Grammarly tells me to remove "about" from this sentence.

> Let me explain about this briefly in the daily meeting.

Here are my questions.

1. Is it really better to remove this "about"? Why?
2. What is the difference in the meaning when using "about" here or not?

I guess using "about" here may not be a grammatical error at least because I find many such examples in the dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the sentence is much more fluent without the *about*.  The simplest answer is "because that's not how we generally speak in English"; [you can see how much more common *explain this* is than *explain about this* is.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=explain%20this%2Cexplain%20about%20this&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

It is not impossible to use *explain* with *about*, but *explain* usually takes a direct object, which is the thing that you are explaining.  "explain *about* X" carries a sense of "to speak generally about things regarding X" rather than "explain a fact or specific situation".

You don't say what dictionary you are looking at, but [Collins at least has many examples of sentences using *explain*, and the great majority do not use *about*.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/sentences/english/explain)

Answer (score 1):

About is included in the meaning of explain, therefore it is redundant or unnecessary. 'Explain' is one of the few words that should rarely be used with about.